# PHP & MySQL pictures not recalling?

Tags: php, mysql

need some help here if possible, I am building a user website with MySQL. Users can sign up, change or add details and add a profile picture. The display picture is where I need help, I've created a form that lets users upload a picture to a file on the website and then sends the name of the picture to their user info in MySQL database to be recalled later. That's all working fine, but no matter how hard I try or what codes I use, I just can't get the photo to show properly or at all?! Here is the current code I'm using after about 50 tries. Also, if you are willing to help, please be detailed as I am new to PHP and MySQL. Thanks.

```
<?php 

session_start();     

Echo "<img src 'http://basecentre.co.uk/user_bc_74hw438eryer90reh0e9rh83232_members/upload/".$_SESSION['photo'] ."> <br>"; 

Echo "<b>Name:</b> ".$_SESSION['first_name'] . "<br> ";

?>
```

This seems to work but doesn't show the image, just shows the logged in users name?

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Do I add that to the code (link)?

Comment: Are you asking how to implement my correction? You just add an `=` between `src` and `'http://...` and then add a closing `'` after the url (`.">` should become `."'>`)

Comment: Ah okay, I get what you mean, just tried that and still have no return on the image link. You can see what I mean here http://basecentre.co.uk/user_bc_74hw438eryer90reh0e9rh83232_members/profile.php

Answer (score 3):

You're missing an `=` sign and a closing `'` on the image `src`:

```
echo "<img src='http://basecentre.co.uk/user_bc_74hw438eryer90reh0e9rh83232_members/upload/".$_SESSION['photo'] ."' /> <br>";
```

Also, it's worth mentioning a few things about your markup here:

1. Don't use the `<b>` tag - the `<strong>` tag is more semantically correct
2. Give your profile image an `alt` tag so browsers know what they're looking at
3. Don't use `<br>` tags to create visual line breaks. It's fine to use them when they are sematically appropriate, but it appears that you're using them for display purposes. You're better off wrapping your content in an appropriate tag (`span`/`div`/`p`/etc) and using `css` to render breaks:

---

```
<div class='profile_img'><img src='[src]' alt='[alt name]'></div>
<dl class='profile_specs'><dt>Name</dt><dd>[Some Value]</dd></dl>
```

Or something like that. It will let you change the layout in the future without messing with the markup (it's also easier to set precise layouts)

Comment: Just changed the code and the image still isn't appearing. You can see what I mean here. http://basecentre.co.uk/user_bc_74hw438eryer90reh0e9rh83232_members/profile.php

Comment: so does that URL actually exist on your server? I'm willing to bet a shiny penny that you'll find it comes out as a 404 in your server's logs.

Comment: Seems to work fine, have created that huge random numbered file on my hosting server to stop people just skipping over to the members area as I haven't created a locking code yet. All the uploaded images are stored behind that link in a file named "upload". The name appears fine on the page, although when I click the broken image icon and click "view image" it comes up with the entire link to that folder "upload/" but the image name doesn't appear afterward as it should?

Comment: Appears like this "Index of /user_bc_74hw438eryer90reh0e9rh83232_members/upload" it should come up like this if it was working as it should "Index of /user_bc_74hw438eryer90reh0e9rh83232_members/upload/image-948.jpg"

Comment: It appears from your link that you're not populating `$_SESSION['photo']` correctly (the source code just says `src='http://basecentre.co.uk/user_bc_74hw438eryer90reh0e9rh83232_members/upload/'`

Comment: So how would I get that to work correctly? Any ideas?

Comment: Well you'd have to (a) check that the photo actually exists somewhere (i.e. try just putting the expected location in the browser address bar... if it doesn't load then it means that the image doesn't exist there or that the webserver is configured not to serve it); and (b) you need to show us how you load the SESSION values in. You haven't provided any details about how this system is designed, so there's no much we can do. You need to do more legwork figuring out where the problem is before we can provide any more insight.